# Importing Excel Documents into Python

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to import an excel file into python on Jupiter. I have tried everything and looked at multiple Q&A's and nothing has worked. I appreciate any help. This is the code I am using.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

'''
Excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Documents\Accounting\Applied_Accounting_Principles\Exercises\Data_Analytics\')
'''

df = pd.read_excel(Excel_file)
```

Comment: try using `pd.read_excel(r'C:\Documents\Accounting\Applied_Accounting_Principles\Exercises\Data_Analytics\your_excel_file.xlsx')` (assuming that the file exists in that directory).

Comment: As pointed out by @jfaccioni, you've to mention the path of your Excel File including the name of the file with `.xlsx` extension. Don't forget to add `r` before you the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, welcome! :)

I played with Excel on my computer and this seemed to work:

```
   Excel_file = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\testingexcel.xlsx') 

   print(Excel_file)
```

Output was (for my excel file) :

```
   Numbers
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
4        5
```

Include the `r` (this is to "read" the file) before placing the file address, including the file ending with `.xlsx`, for example `r'C:\Users\Ben\Documents\excelfile.xlsx'`

If you want to just print columns you can also utilize the `pd.DataFrame(Excel_file, columns=['Column Name'])`

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!